# programmatically Copy/Move folder/file in one document library to another document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have a library like below :

```
List
---------Folder 1
---------File 0
---------File 1
-----------------Folder 2
------------------------File 2
------------------------File 3
---------Folder 3
-----------------File 4
-----------------File 5
```

The plan is to copy it to another library, i have found a way to copy the File 0 / File 1. But i'm looking for a way to copy all the library (folder with subfolder and file inside) to my other library.

To copy the file i  did this:

```
SPListItem item = oldLib.GetItemById(collItem[i].ID);
byte[] fileBytes = item.File.OpenBinary();
string destUrl = newlib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + item.File.Name;
SPFile destFile = newlib.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, true);
```

Did i miss an easy way to do what i want?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPFile [CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.copyto.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) / [MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.moveto.aspx) methods.

`file.CopyTo(destUrl, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder()**  method to Move Folder From one Document Library to another Document Library. Instead of Coping file from one document library to another.
Try to use Following code, It's work for me :-

```
function moveFolder() {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder(context, 
  "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/DocumentLibraryOne/Folder", 
  "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/DocumentLibraryTwo/Folder");

   context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        alert("success.");
    }, function (sender, args) {
           alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' 
 +args.get_stackTrace());
});
}, "sp.js");
}
```